# Как создать экземпляр с помощью Dagger2?

Tags: android, dagger2

Изучаю работу Dagger2 с MVP. Как я понял, что в Presenter-e не должен создаваться объект на прямую, а подаётся готовым со стороны.Есть класс модели с конструктором, его объект я и пытаюсь получить с помощью Dagger-а, но не понимаю, как заинжектить String (возможно ли это вообще?). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать или обойти.

```
public class Budget  {

public String mBudgetMoney;

public String mBudgetText;

public String mBudgetDate;

public String mBudgetIdentifier;

private ArrayList<Budget> mDetails;

@Inject
public Budget(@NonNull String mBudgetText, @NonNull String mBudgetMoney) {
    this.mBudgetText = mBudgetText;
    this.mBudgetMoney = mBudgetMoney;
    this.mBudgetDate = new Date().toString();
    this.mBudgetIdentifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Comment: Зачем инжектить String в модель. Модель инжектится в презентер. mBudgetText и mBudgetMoney, если они приходят из активити, то нужно передавать в презентер, а потом передавать в модель

Comment: Даггер не должен использоваться для передачи модели. Он обычно используется для передачи репозиториев(знаете что это такое?)